# regex not accepting white space

Tags: java, regex

Below is a code snippet :

```
    String reFundId = "(\\s{0,})<fund_id>([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,8}\\s)</fund_id>(\\s\\S0,})";
    Pattern patFundId = Pattern.compile(reFundId, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    String text = "<fund_id>AB11 </fund_id>";
    String fundVar = parseFundId(text,patFundId);
```

---

```
public static String parseFundId(String text,Pattern patFundId)
    {
        String fund_id = null;
        Matcher mat = patFundId.matcher("" + text);
        if (mat.find())
        {
            String s = mat.group(2);
            fund_id = (s != null ? s.trim() : null);
        }
        return fund_id;
    }
```

Regex pattern is not accepting `<fund_id>AB11 </fund_id>`. What changes are required in regex pattern?

Comment: Isn't the last section missing left curly bracket? `(\\s\\S0,})` => `(\\s\\S{0,})`

Comment: Also `{0,}` can generally be replaced with `*`, and `{1,}` with `+`

Comment: @peter it's option value, might come or might not.

Comment: @Nirmal have a look at my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do it, and it works with multiple spaces as well:

```
String reFundId = "(\\s*)<fund_id>([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,8}\\s*)</fund_id>(\\s*)";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have unescaped forward slash in `</fund_id>`. Just replace it with `<\\/fund_id>`. Also you lack square brackets at the end. Replace `\\s\\S0,}` with `[\\s\\S]*`.

Comment: There might be multiple spaces, in that case [\\s\\S]* will work ?

Comment: Actually `[\\s\\S]*` matches any number of any characters. If you want just to match multiple spaces use `\\s*`

Comment: String reFundId = "(\\s{0,})<fund_id>([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,8}\\s)</fund_id>\\s*"; This one still not working ?

Comment: Just use parentheses around last `\\s*` like `(\\s*) to create matching group.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your regex. Change this:

```
"(\\s{0,})<fund_id>([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,8}\\s)</fund_id>(\\s\\S0,})";
```

To

```
"(\\s{0,})<fund_id>([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,8}\\s)</fund_id>(\\s\\S{0,})";
                                               missing --^
```